# What would cause a new EVAP canister to fail after 6 months, 3,000 miles?

Tags: toyota, evap, tacoma

When I bought my truck two years ago, it started throwing all sorts of codes. As I sorted them out, the last one I was dragging my feet on was replacing the EVAP canister, which I was told the switch in it had completely failed and Toyota only sells the entire thing as a whole unit. Finally, $600 later, I installed it this February. A few weeks ago, my CEL light came back on, and the codes and suggested fixes all point to the EVAP canister again. What, from a mechanical perspective, would cause an EVAP canister to fail that fast? It is an OEM part, directly from Toyota. I wonder if there is a bigger issue going on with my truck to cause the canisters to fail?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year/engine is your Tacoma?

Comment: You can destroy a canister by filling your gas tank after the nozzle clicks off. (to round it up to an even dollar amount.)  what makes you think it is the canister? What are the codes? I have a 2001 4runner Sr5 that threw codes for the evap system and everything pointed to the canister. Did a bit of research and I have 3 solinoid valves related to the EVAP system, 2 under the hood and 1 on top of the charcoal canister under the back of truck. From my understanding, the 4runner and Tacoma use many of the same parts, just the bodies are different. I changed valves and all is good.

Comment: It's a 2003 Tacoma. Thanks for tips on everything else that might be throwing the codes. The codes I have right now are P0446, P0442, P0441.